# How to create function like CTRL+F to get string on PDF & HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, find

I want to ask how to create function like CTRL+F for my search bar on my HTML. for simple example here I have a code at my body html like this :

```
    <form class="example">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
    </form>
```

I want to find some text with that search bar function (like CTRL+F function), I have a PDF file on my HTML, my goal is i can find some text on that PDF, where the pdf is raised in my html. i want find some text on that PDF with my find function. someone can guide me ? I'm so tired of trying every way I find on google but always fail... oh yeah, usually I'm trying with javascript code.

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: i have trying this http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php, search bar can be used, but can't search/find text on PDF in my HTML (PDF is raised in my HTML).

Comment: So you have a PDF on your website and you want to be able to search it? PDFs are not really designed for the web, and you'd be better off converting the PDF contents to HTML. You could offer the PDF as an additional download.

Comment: May I know which pdf plugin you are using or have you written your own?

Comment: i have a data in PDF format, This PDF is used by some people, this website is made to make it easier to see the data and search it via the web.  maybe someone have an new idea ?

Comment: Please don't put code, relevant to your question, in a comment, add it to your question. People read your question first, and comments later, or not.

Comment: okay, i'm so sorry for my mistake, thanks for your correction.

Comment: I would always offer data both on the website and as a PDF download, not just a PDF. If you're on a phone or a tablet, accessing PDFs can be a nuisance and they are formatted for printing, so they're often not easy to read. PDF was designed for printing, not for the web.

Comment: if i convert to excel, can be display and find it with my find function ?

Comment: Any embedded file is going to be difficult to search, and if you use Excel, it means that your users also need to have excel to be able to read the file. If you have tabular data, there are some good searchable tables you could implement -- e.g. https://datatables.net

Comment: thank you for sharing knowledge with me, may be useful for me *hope